totally geodesic manifolds
We choose the Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $$g=e^{-2z}dx^2+e^{2z}dy^2+dz^2$$Let $\mathcal{H}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:y=0\}$ and $\mathcal{F}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=0\}$.
i) $\mathcal{H}$ is isometric to the hyperbolic plane and  $\mathcal{F}$ is isometric to the euclidian plane
ii) Are the above surfaces totally geodesic?
$\mathcal{H}$ is obviously diffeomorphic with the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now in $g=dx^2+dz^2$ I should change coordinates so that i get $g=\frac{1}{v^2}(du^2+dv^2)$? As for totally geodesic, should i check if $B=0$? Is there any other way?

None of the questions make sense as written. You have to start by fixing a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb R^3$ to talk about geometry of submanifolds. And the right terminology is "a surface is totally geodesic", not "a surface is totally geodesically."

@MoisheKohan I have edited it now, thank you

For starters, what are some diffeomorphisms between the half-plane and the plane? Then think about pulling back the metric by such a diffeomorphism.

$\mathcal H$ is totally geodesic, because the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,0,z)$ is a $1$-Lipschitz retract.
$\mathcal F$ is not totally geodesic, because if you take the segment $[-m,m] \times \{0\} \times \{0\} \subset \mathcal F \cap \mathcal H$ then it is a geodesic in the Euclidean plane $\mathcal F$, but in the hyperbolic plane $\mathcal H$ that segment lies on a horocycle and therefore, for large $m$, it's endpoints have distance in $\mathcal F$ comparable to $\log(m)$.
